# EthGasStation accuracy

Tags: gas, pending-transactions

I have posted a transaction with a very low gas fee (11 gwei) to the txn pool. Speed wasn't an issue and I can wait for the txn to post.

This was 24 hours ago, and the txn is still pending.

Currently, ethgasstation dot info states that 24% of the last 200 blocks have accepted txn's at 11 gwei and 20% of the last 200 blocks have accepted txns at 8 gwei.

Is ethgasstation accurate? If 8 gwei transactions have been added in the last 200 blocks, why is my 11 gwei transaction still pending?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 20% stats only means that if gas price ever gets that low, 20% of the block will accept a transaction with a 8 gwei gas price. I does not mean that they have actually been included in a block, only that they would if the market price got that low. However, I doubt price will get down that much any time soon if ever.

After some time, transactions that are not mined just get excluded from the tx pool. You should increase your gas price for that transaction if you want it to go through.