# Why transaction is still pending?

Tags: pending-transactions

I have created a transaction some days ago. It has status Pending and gas price 82 gwei.

Today at [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/gastracker#historicaldata) I can see a minimal low gas price is 73 gwei.
And a minimal average gas price has the same value.
It is the first day my gas price is more than that gas price.

1. Why my transaction is still pending?
2. What's the process of choosing a transaction to include in the block?
3. Can this transaction be processed in future or not?

**UPDATE**:

There are blocks of transactions that have minimal low gas price is 70 gwei.

[image]

**UPDATE**:
[image]

How we can see chart from the update yesterday (Apr 19) we have the minimum average gas price is 73 gwei. I create my transaction on Apr 18. I understand there was the moment when the average price was downing till 73 gwei.

Maybe I understand wrong, but if the gas price was less my price so the transaction must be included in a block already, otherwise I'm reading this chart and legend wrong. But my transaction is still pending at this moment...

Comment: Similar case - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94592/ethgasstation-accuracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miners usually include transactions with a higher gas price but they can include any transactions even with 0 wei gas price.

- Mine their reward distribution transactions at a nominal 1 gwei gas price.
- Accept off-chain payments.
- Flashbot transactions process several transactions as a group.

Transactions with gas price away from the last average gas price isn't like they are going to be included in the next block.

So unless the average gas price gets close to 82 gwei your transaction is unlikely to be mined.

Comment: I've updated the post. Do you want to say that miners can include transactions in blocks with a specific order and/or price and that I don't have to look at minimal average gas price? Yes, 73 gwei was yesterday but it was a specific deal. I'm confused about how it understand?

Comment: @Mr.JE If the average is 177 gwei the 73 gwei minimum is not real. It is the result of miners including transactions with very low gas price, but they get paid off-chain or with a token transfer that aren't considered for the graph. I would say that with an average of 177 gwei a regular transaction with less than 150 gwei is unlikely to be mined.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks. How do you think what value (min, avg, max) and what line (blue, grey, green) I better use for setting the price of gas at a simple transaction (transfer cryptos) where I'll be sure (more or less) that transaction will include to?

Comment: @Mr.JE I don't think there are precise rules that work all the time. For ether transfers usually some points below average is enough. For contract deployments, defi interactions, token swaps, etc usually you want a speedy time so start above average, and increase gas price if it taking too long. Check several sites for gas price etherscan, ethgasstation, etc. If the gas is too high due to network congestion sometimes it is better to wait if you can.

Comment: I have arisen another question. How I understand if I leave my transaction in the pending transactions pool it will be processed if the price of gas will be appropriate, even if the transaction would be in status "Pending" for many months. In other words, do the transaction have an end time (live time) in the pending transactions pool?

Comment: @Mr.JE Pending transactions don't have an 'end date'. Eventually a node may drop them if it takes too long but another node may keep it a little longer and it may resend it again to the node that dropped it.

Comment: Ok. How I understand my transaction have the opportunity to be processed in future if the gas price will be to down to appropriate level. I will wait some time. Thank you a lot again. :)